# How to add some variable to $scope.master object from controller in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

My issue is how to add some variable in $scope.master object from the controller.

I'm saving some data to db on angular form submit.

And the goal is to automatically save 'date_create' variable on form submit. So I need to have it in angular's $scope.master object by default. And for that, as I think, I need to push it to $scope.master in the controller.

What I have now and it doesn't work:

```
app.controller('AddController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    var currentDate = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    $scope.master = {};
    // I've tried to add variable from here
    // $scope.master = {date_update: currentDate};
    $scope.activePath = null;

    // function which triggers on form submit
    $scope.addNew = function(product, AddNewForm) {
        $http.post('api/add', product).success(function(data){
            // And also I've tried to add it from here
            $scope.master.date_update = currentDate;
            console.log(data);
            $scope.reset();
            $scope.activePath = $location.path('/products');
        });
        $scope.reset = function() {
            $scope.product = angular.copy($scope.master);
        };

        $scope.reset();
    };
}]);
```

**Logs:**

```
Object {name: "123", category_id: "3", date_update: null, id: "11"}
```

Comment: `$scope.master = {"date_update": currentDate};` have u tried this?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Do you have any error logs?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. Please see the updated quetions with log.

Comment: are you logging product or master?

Comment: Add it before the `$http.post`

Comment: @YangLi I'm logging product

Comment: console log the value of your currentDate before you assign it to the master.date_update. what do you see there?

Comment: You need to log product after your $scope.reset(); @Alliswell

Comment: @manasisakhare When I log just currentDate, it is ok, not null.

Comment: Please do a $scope.$apply() or $scope.$digest() after your $scope.master.date_update = currentDate; statement

Comment: @Alliswell do you want to send that date while posting product data?

Comment: @YangLi, logging after reset returns without **date_update** at all.

Comment: @manasisakhare why we need $scope.$apply(), as `$http' had already have capability to run digest cycle

Comment: @pankajparkar I want to send **date_create** variable with other data from the form.

Comment: @Alliswell check my answer..hopefully this would help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append the data while doing post you could simply use `angular.extend` method OR more simpler way would would be you can access that object using literal & set its value.

**Code**

```
$scope.addNew = function(product, AddNewForm) {
    angular.extend({}, product, {date_update: currentDate});
    //product["date_update"] =  currentDate; //this is alternative
    $http.post('api/add', product).success(function(data){
        // And also I've tried to add it from here
        console.log(data);
        $scope.reset();
        $scope.activePath = $location.path('/products');
    });
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.product = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };

    $scope.reset();
};
```

Comment: check it once more ;)